# Как получить размерность int в байтах ? Без использования sizeof

Tags: c

Это каким-то образом связано с переполнением?

Comment: Ну да. Вы можете взять максимально возможное значение для предполагаемой длины int и сделать +1, если получили 0, значит переолнилось. Или делаете 0-1 и считаете единичные биты (сдвигом)

Comment: @Mike,и как тогда получится 4 байта ?

Comment: количество бит на 8 поделите вот вам и длина в байтах. И почему вы думаете, что получите именно 4 ? ;)

Comment: @Mike,переполненный 0 делить на 8 ? зачем?

Comment: @Mike,а разве размерность инт не 4 ?

Comment: не 0, а количество битов которое посчитаете сдвигом (в одном байте 8 бит). А размер зависит от целевой платформы компилятора. Кроме 4 я встречал и 2 и 8

Comment: Не слушайте @Mike, его совет - UB.

Comment: @int3 Ну я имел ввиду все таки unsigned int. понятно что переполнение знаковых стандартами не оговорено

Comment: @Mike, ну побитовым сдвигом доходим до переполнения , а потом  -1 , и если это число разделить на 8, то я получу размерность  в байтах? Вряд ли

Comment: @Elvin Нет, сначала переполнение, а потом сдвигом вправо считаем пока не будет 0. 0-1 это все биты установленные в 1

Comment: хотя да, можно просто 1 двигать влево пока в 0 не превратится

Comment: @Mike, не понял , поясни ,пожалуйста

Comment: Вы путаете размерность и размер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для беззнаковых сработает такой вариант

```
unsigned int a = (unsigned int)-1;
unsigned int bits = 1;
while (a >>= 1) bits++;
unsigned int bytes = bits / 8;
```

Впрочем, количество бит в байте не оговорено стандартом.

Comment: расшифруй а>>=1

Comment: `a = a >> 1;` или `a = a / 2;`

Comment: нет , именно в while там же типо условие ==0 или !=0 ?

Comment: До тех пор, пока a / 2 не 0 ..

Comment: @int3 Кстати интересно, что говорит стандарт при сдвиге 1 стоящей в следующем за старшим битом влево на 1 для знаковых. оно гарантирует что получим отрицательное значение или то же UB

Comment: @Elvin Результат любой арифметической операции в C возвращается. А while всегда работает пока результат не 0 (вернее не flase, но 0 к false приводится)

Comment: `-1` использует переполнение, лучше делать побитовую инверсию. Также используется допущение, что в байте 8 бит. В `limits.h` есть `CHAR_BIT`, определяющий количество бит в байте.

Comment: @Abyx, если использовать битовое отрицание, то лучше `~0u`, ибо используя `~0` можно получить, гипотетически, trap representation.

Comment: @Ternvein, код `(unsigned int)-1` является корректным, и результирующее значение — `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @wololo, да. Я не писал, что он некорректен, я написал, что побитовая инверсия не будет использовать переполнение.

Answer (score 2):

Кроссплатформенный вариант подсчета для беззнаковых типов:

```
unsigned int a = ~(0U);
unsigned char count = 0;
do {
    count++;
} while (a >>= 1);
count /= CHAR_BIT;
```

Вместо `~(0U)` можно использовать `UINT_MAX`, представленный вместе с `CHAR_BIT` в заголовочном файле `limits.h`.

Answer (score 2):

Простой способ:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>

size_t bits = 0;
int    x = INT_MAX;

while (x)
{
    ++bits;
    x = x / 2;
}
size_t bytes = (bits + 1) / CHAR_BIT;
```

Однако, вообще говоря, стандарт языка допускает, что в представлении целочисленных типов могут присутствовать padding bits, которые не участвуют в формировании значения типа, а значит не будут подсчитаны приведённым выше способом.

Альтернативный способ, основанный на арифметике указателей, и для которого не существенно наличие padding bits:

```
int x = 0;
int *begin, *end;

begin = &x;
end   = begin + 1;
ptrdiff_t bytes = (unsigned char *)end - (unsigned char *)begin;
```

Comment: Да, на указателях, пожалуй, самый надежный способ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё так (это ведь гипотетический вопрос, да?):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

// через логарифм:
lround(log2(UINT_MAX) / CHAR_BIT);

// посредством подсчёта количества бит:
__builtin_popcount(UINT_MAX) / CHAR_BIT;
```